# Скрипты на платформе

Tags: javascript, jquery

Написал код который определяет место человека из таблицы по баллам. И если я впишу его просто на страницу(в специальный блок для js) он не работает, когда ввожу в консоль на странице то действие происходит. Что нужно сделать чтоб он работал? Таблица подгружается с другой страницы, если вдруг это важно. Если поможет то, платформа Getcourse.
Вот код

```
    var num_reyt = 0;
    var score = $('.xdget-trainingAchievements .badge').html().split(' ')[0];
    var ar = document.querySelectorAll(".user-rating tbody td:nth-child(2)");
    var spisok = [];
    
    
    for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        content = ar[i].innerText
        spisok.push(content);
    }
    
    console.log(spisok)
    for (var m = 0; m < spisok.length; i++) {
        if (spisok[m] == score) {
            num_reyt = m + 1;
            break;
        }
    
    }
    $(".scn").text(num_reyt);
```

Comment: в браузере в консоли разработчика можно посмотреть проблемы в коде. Скорей всего ваш скрипт отрабатывает раньше, чем загрузилась вся страница

Comment: Если у вас скрипт отдельным файлом, то тогда добавьте атрибут `defer` к элементу `<script>` в котором вы и подгружаете скрипт. В противоположном случае заверните всё в эту конструкцию: `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { /* ваш код тут */ })`